# Are there any rapid-transit spells that can be achieved without rego?

Tags: ars-magica-5

My players have collectively decided to shy away from Rego as a technique this campaign as a stylistic choice<sup>*</sup>. However, this does inhibit their rapid-transit capabilities quite significantly as (ReCo, ReTe, CrAu(Re)) are the notable "get from point a to point b in a hurry" forms.

**Are there any other base guidelines in non-rego techniques that can provide for acceptable rapid-transit capabilities, preferably exceeding a horse's speed?**

<sup>*</sup> Their last campaign featured incredible amounts of Rego useage and they feel that they've explored that technique particularly well.

Answer (score 2):

There's the ever-popular MuCo(An), that can change you into a bird. The basic rulebook even has Cloak of Black Feathers for it - MuCo(an) 30, pg.131 according to [this](http://www.atlas-games.com/pdf_storage/SpellIndexbyForm.pdf). You can adapt this for other animals too.

I'm playing a Muto specialist right now and I'm working my way towards some variant of that for long-range travel, but I may go for a land-bound form. Slower, but more versatile to travel with company.

Comment: MuCo(Au) to make you as light as the wind - floating with the breezes. You'll be limited to the direction and speed of the wind.

Comment: You could do something similar to aramis' suggestion by using PeCo to destroy the weight of a character - but then you'd have the problem of getting it back again when you get wherever you're going.

Comment: Also, both of these suggestions will leave you floating fine and free, but you'll need to rely on ReAu to actually go somewhere. That, or tie yourself to a horse and set him riding. Now that I think about it, I think we actually did something similar with Rise of the Feathery Body once.